# How to fetch value from json object in angular 2

Tags: json, angular

How to fetch value from json object in angular 2? My Object is as follows:
[image]

Here I want to fetch value of **type**.

**I tried following ways:**

1. console.log("RECORD TYPE IS:"+**records.type**);
2. console.log**(records['type'])**;

But it is printing **undefined**.

Comment: Can you paste the response from the response of chrome dev tools instead of preview tab.

Also try to `console.log(typeof records)`

Answer (score 0):

Your record object has type so you should try

```
console.log(record['type']);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the json write as Records conidering Records is your class/interace name and type is a field name.
Example :

```
var record=yourObjectName as Records
console.log(record.type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a wrapping object to `record` which in JSON will be represented as follow:

```
var Object = {
 record: {
  id: 30,
  recordno: "2",
  type: "dynamic"
 }
}
```

Therefore the correct way to read this object is:

```
console.log(Object.record.type);
```

Full code example:

```js
var Object = {
     record: {
      id: 30,
      recordno: "2",
      type: "dynamic"
     }
    };
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Object type is: " + Object.record.type;
```

```html
<span id="test"></span>
```